# How to add child screens within activity_main.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I wanted this hierarchy in my activity_main.xml:
-Calling screen(call log, dial pad etc.)
-Music screen
-Reminders Screen

How can I have this hierarchy of child screens within One Parent Screen(activity_main.xml) ?[image: please see the picture, for a clear idea about what am trying to do.]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: show what you have done so far

Comment: Can not say more without looking at how much is done. But, you can always go for the fragment to show a different type of layout in a single Activity.

Comment: @RudrikPatel thanks for the fragment suggestion, should I keep these child screens within a drawer or a tab-pager or is there any other way to put these up for the selection of screens ?

Comment: @UbaidKhan that is entirely up to the design that you want to follow. Both are serving the same solution for displaying multiple screens in the same Activity.

Comment: What do you want exactly? As you have different screens for Reminders, Music etc .Why you wont all these is activity main? What is the actual concern of doing that. You can tell you requirement first.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput this screen above is an individual screen(The app does have several other screens) this is particularly "Phone Interface" it is supposed to have child screens as depicted in the above picture.

Comment: To be more specific I have multiple Screens(categorized by the views they'll consist) which have child screens within them.

Comment: But you can show only one UI at a time, that is what I am asking. If they are different screens you can use fragment and replace with required screen whenever needed. Having all the UI in single screen is a bad idea. If you really want this you can create different UI and include it in the main activity.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput got it thanks, one thing though can I have such screens(as shown in picture above i.e. calling, music & reminders )inside a fragment ?

Comment: Your picture is displaying a number of screens. What you actually want , only you know. As we are seeing a number of screens that can be replaced by fragments.

Comment: it's easier if you create multiple XML files, then load them as a fragment in the main view.
refer to this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments